# Xamarin forms: Gif image is not working with FFimageloading in UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, gif, ffimageloading

I am using `FFImageLoading` for playing a gif file in my project. It is working fine on android and ios but not working in UWP.

I have added the following NuGet packages to every project in my solution.

1. Xamarin.FFImageLoading.
2. Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms.
3. Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Transformations.
4. Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.
5. Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms.

Added the following code on UWP `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init();
```

In XAML:

```
xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"

<ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage 
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
    x:Name="GifImage" 
    Grid.Row="0"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    WidthRequest="200"
    HeightRequest="200"
    Source="ic_dove_loading_xx.gif"/>
```

Gif is not playing in the UWP app. Are there any additional settings in the windows part for UWP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not available for UWP in my knowledge, Last time I checked it was an enhancement that was not added.

**UPDATE**

When you check FFImageLoading's Github issues there is an [open issue](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/1061) about this where the reason is explained by the Author.

> It's because FFImageLoading is using WriteableBitmap internally. We'll need to add a new logic to handle this and don't use WriteableBitmap for animated gifs.

The good thing is that they have added this as a future enhancement for v2.5 which should be out soon!

Comment: that will never happen :)